# Symbian merging of one sis file to other sis file

Tags: symbian

I'm working on a Symbian project where I'm trying to install an application from the server. The problem is that there are two SIS files coming from the server for the same application.
How do I merge the two SIS files and install the result on the device?

Answer (score 2):

you can use embedded sis in .pkg file
add string in firstApp.pkg

```
@secondApp.sis
```

and run makesis

secondApp.sis will be built in firstApp.sis

Answer (score 1):

Why merge? Just install them separately - if you can install one then you can install two.

If these 2 SIS files are also created by you then you can insert one into another.